# Get whether key existed from ConcurrentMap.remove()

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

In Java's [`ConcurrentMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html), there's [`remove(key, expectedValue)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#remove%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29), this returns one of:

- The expected value was there and has been removed.
- The expected value was not there, so has not been removed.

But what I want to get is one of:

1. The expected value was there and has been removed.
2. There is a value under that key, but not the expected one, so it has not been removed.
3. There is no value under that key, so it has not been removed.

How can I get this information in a concurrent and thread-safe way?

---

This is the code I'm trying to safify

```
// attempt to remove the old session...
if (!sessions.remove(player.getId(), existing)) {
    // it was not removed...
    if (sessions.containsKey(player.getId())) { // TODO threadsafe
        // ...because in the meantime some other thread logged in as that user
        throw new ServiceError(LobbyService.ERR_LOGIN_INVALID, Maps.create("reason", "already-logged-in"));
    } else {
        // ...because it was no longer there, which is as it should be
    }
} else {
    // it was removed, which is bad, because it shouldn't have been there still
    log.warn("Kicking old session of " + player.getId() + " failed");
}
```

Or generalised:

```
if (!sessions.remove(key, expected)) {
    if (sessions.containsKey(key)) {    // TODO threadsafe
        // 2
    } else {
        // 3
    }
} else {
    // 1
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `sessions.remove(player.getId(), existing)` instead of `sessions.remove(sessions, existing)` ?

Comment: Can you describe the overall picture of how you use that map?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand between what you saw in the doc and what you want. So please let me write things down.

- key `A` is associated with value `B`. `remove(A, B)` will return true **and** remove mapping A->B (which is what you want).
- key `A` is associated with value `C`. `remove(A, B)` will return `false`, mappping A->C won't be removed (which is what you want).
- key `A` is associated with no value. `remove(A, null)` will return `false` (which is what you want).

In other words, it seems like remove precisely does what you want ... or maybe there is another bug in your code.

Comment: You describe my problem exactly, neither of the latter two cases both remove the entry from the map (which is what I want) and they also return the same result, `false`, which is not enough information, because I need to distinguish between the two situations in the code that comes after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AtomicReference to help. Assuming you prepoulate with a non-null AtomicReference, you can attempt to null the value in the session with the predicate that the reference's current value is `existing`.  If it is, you 'removed' from the map else the current value of the AtomicReference is what is currently existing

```
AtomicReference<Session> ref = session.get(player.getId());
if (ref.compareAndSet(existing,null) {
   //1
}else{
   Session current = ref.get();
   if(current != null){
       //2
   }else{
      //3
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to **nearly** offer what you are asking for but I am not sure if it gives you what you want.

Could you please expand on what you actually want to do?

```
class Player {};
ConcurrentMap<String,Player> players = new ConcurrentHashMap();

void playerIDChanged(String id, Player oldPlayer, Player newPlayer) {
  Player old = players.replace(id, newPlayer);
  if ( old == oldPlayer ) {
    // The expected value was there and has been REPLACED.
  } else {
    if ( old == null ) {
      // There is no value under that key, so it has not been removed.
    } else {
      // There is a value under that key, but not the expected one, so it HAS been replaced.
      // NB: This is slightly different from what you are asking for.
    }
  }
}
```